# Почему рекурсия так работает?

Tags: javascript, list, объекты, рекурсия

```js
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};

function printReverseList(list) {

  if (list.next) {
    printReverseList(list.next);
  }

  alert(list.value);
}

printReverseList(list);
```

*Я понимаю как он выводит последний элемент. Но как он выводит предпоследние элементы ?*

Comment: Что значит "как он выводит предпоследние элементы" ?  А что должен выводить по вашей логике?

Comment: Потому что так работает рекурсия)) Вы выводите элемент, если нет дочерних элеметнов, иначе разбираете дочерние. После разбора последнего вложенного уровня дочерних возвращаетесь и выводите элементы уровней.

Answer (score 0):

У вас функция устроена как:

```
if (list.next) {
    printReverseList(list.next);
}

alert(list.value);
```

- Если соблюдается условие - выполнить инструкции в блоке `{}`
- Независимо от того, выполнилось ли условие, в любом случае выполнить `alert(list.value);`

Вот и всё. Обычное чтение инструкций сверху вниз. Поэтому независимо на сколько глубоко закопается рекурсия, после того, как отработают все инструкции в самом последнем блоке `if` самой последней вложенности, код продолжит выполняться дальше и выполнит один `alert` затем функция закончится и курсор выйдет из функции и выполнится другой `alert`, затем функция закончится и курсор выйдет из функции и выполнится другой `alert`, затем.....

---

Схематично получилось так:

```
if (list.next) { -----------------------------------------|
    if (list.next) { --------------------------------|    |
        if (list.next) { -----------------------|    |    |
            if (list.next) { ---------------|   |    |    |
                if (list.next) {            |   |    |    |
                    // выполнили  ----|     |   |    |    |
                }                     |     |   |    |    |
                                      |     |   |    |    |
                alert(list.value);  <-|     |   |    |    |
            }                       | ------|   |    |    |
                                    |           |    |    |
            alert(list.value);    <-|           |    |    |
        }                         |   ----------|    |    |
                                  |                  |    |
        alert(list.value);      <-|                  |    |
    }                           |    ----------------|    |
                                |                         |
    alert(list.value);        <-|                         |
}                             |      ---------------------|    
                              |
alert(list.value);          <-|
```